# How can i add a folder like dependency at pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I am adding like 8 libraries to my pom.xml with the next template, but i would like to set only one dependency that contains all the folder´s jars.

I have already tried to set only the folder name without the "xxx.jar" and is not working.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>CCF2</groupId>
        <artifactId>CCF"</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ccf2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
 .............
```

At the folder libs, i have like 8 jars, if i use 8 templates is working, but i want to summarize all that lines.
Is possible to do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Working with scope `system` is only recommended in exceptional circumstances. Usually, dependencies should be kept in a Maven repository (Nexus/Artifactory).

Including directories of jars into a Maven build is not supported (and not recommended).

Comment: Thanks! I finally upload my jars to a Nexus. Sorry for the late.